# Logitech G pro wireless: DPI settings when turned on

Tags: logitech-mouse

I'm working with the onboard memory profile (win10). I set the default color and DPI (1600).
When I turn on the mouse (using the on/off button), all the settings are restored, however the current dpi is set to 800.

Meaning, when I run the onboard memory manager, it shows the default dpi as 1600, but the active as 800, and then I need to right click on the 1600 setting and set it as active.

What am I missing, doesn't the default dpi mean that when I turn it on, that's what it's set to?

---

The button on the bottom of the mouse cycles through the DPIs. It sets the DPI and overrides any onboard memory profile settings. So just use this button to set the dpi.